# Python: How to search a build file for a specific string and replace it with a user input string

Tags: python, search, replace

I have searched a text file mobileBuildSettings for specific strings determined by user input and I have copied those strings. This piece of code works perfectly fine I have tested it.

My problem is as follows:
I then try to search a build file called abproject for @AppIdentifier@ and replace it with a string I found in mobileBuildSettings. My code gives no errors but it doesn't do anything.

This next block of code searches the mobileBuildSettings file for the appID, displayName, bundleVersion and andoidVersionCode of the CUID that was entered by the user. This code works fine

```
projectFile = open("C:/settings/mobileBuildSettings.txt" , "r")
    for line in projectFile:
    CUID = str(CUID)
    if CUID + " - " in line:
        appIdentifier = next(projectFile).split("=")[1]
        displayName = next(projectFile).split("=")[1]
        bundleVersion = next(projectFile).split("=")[1]
        next(projectFile)
        androidVersionCode = next(projectFile).split("=")[1]

        print (appIdentifier, displayName, bundleVersion, androidVersionCode)

        break
```

I do not get any errors with the following code but as far as I can tell it doesn't do anything.
This code is supposed to find appID in the abproject file and replace it with the appID from the mobileBuildSettings file.

```
abproject = open("C:/abproject.build", "r")
#appIdentifier = str(appIdentifier)
apid = ("@AppIdentifier@")
for line in abproject:
  if ("@AppIdentifier@") in abproject:
    #line=line.replace(("@AppIdentifier@"),appIdentifier)
```

This is code I tried but it didn't work either.

```
  print(line.replace(apid, appIdentifier))
break
abproject.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do the same thing a few days ago, here is my solution :

1. Open the file
2. Parse it line by line and replace the string you want to rplace
3. Store every line in a temp file
4. When you're done, delete the old file and rename the temp file as the new file

Here is some code :

```
    with open("originalFile.txt", "r+") as script, open("tempfile.txt", "w+") as newscript :
#Go through the file line by line
        for line in script.readlines():
            #print(line)
#Search for a specific pattern in the line (line object is a string)
            if line[4:12] == "MyPattern" :
#Replace this line by an other
                newscript.write("myText")               
            else :
#Else, add the standard line to the temp file
                newscript.write(line)
#Close both files
        script.close()
        newscript.close()
#Delete the old file, and rename the file with replaced text
    os.remove("originalFile.txt")
    os.rename("tempfile.txt", "originalFile.txt")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I am new to Python and I really do not understand the majority of that code. Would you mind adding a comment to the lines explaining what each line of code is doing?

Comment: Of course, i will do that. Plus the code is a bit clearer, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful! Can I ask what the [4:12] part is?

Comment: It is a way to access some member of a list object : str = "abcdefgh", str[2:4] will be the following python object : "bcde".